# extrair dados de uma lista html com php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para filmes online, apenas para fins de aprendizado.
a pagina home esta quase pronta, nela aprece a grade com as categorias, ao clicar em uma, abre a janela com os filmes, ta tudo funcionado ate ai, buscando os dados no banco de dados e tudo.
baixei um exemplo de um site com CTRL+S, e ajustei ate encaixar na pagina, so que agora eu queria pegar os dados desse exemplo e passar para o banco de dados, como CTRL+S salva tudo em html, queria saber se tem como extrair esse dados do html e passar para o banco, pois passar um a um da muito trabalho

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: preciso extrair os dados da lista (ul/li) do aquivo html e montar um array com esses dados para fazer o insert no banco de dados

Answer (score -2, accepted):

consegui usando JQuery, atribui uma classe para as tags `<a>` e `<img>` e extrai os dados usando o `.attr()`

```
$("#lista li").each(function(index,element){
    arrayDeLinhas.push(  { 
        filme: $(element).find(".filme").attr("title"),
        img: $(element).find(".styles_cover__2tUW8").attr('src')

    });
});
```

Comment: Para aceitar a própria resposta você deve [aguardar 48 horas após a postagem da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), então provavelmente você já deve conseguir aceitar sua própria resposta. Segue um guia de como marcar uma resposta como aceita - [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3774)

Answer (score -4):

Utilize o inspecionar da página clicanco com o direito do mouse, ou precionando o F12 e indo para a guia elements(Elelmentos se estiver traduzido), ai voce vai ter todo o codigo fonte da pagina html, e pode copiar os trechos que achar melhor, ou utilizando o CTRL + U para abrir o codigo fonte, e copiar de lá as informações.

Comment: valeu amigo, mais o problema não é obter o html, o problema é extrair a lista dos fimes no aquivo html, são muitos items para passar manualmente para o banco de dados.  eu queria montar um scrpit  php ou javascrit pra ler a lista e montar um array pra fazer o inset no banco de dados.